# Generate a JSON string using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json

I know there are a few frameworks to parse JSON, but how can I generate a JSON string in Objective-C?  Will it be something I would have to write myself, or is there something simple already out there?

Comment: This has been asked many times before. Please spend a minute to peruse SO before asking new questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000599/how-to-send-an-array-of-object-from-iphone-app-to-a-php-script-with-json   /  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895708/saving-and-editing-json-on-iphone-ipod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally like [`json-framework`](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/)'s use of categories on `NSObject` over having to go through `TouchJSON`'s `CJSONDataSerializer` interface.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"b" forKey:@"a"];
NSString *json = [dict JSONRepresentation];
```

Answer (score 0):

TouchJSON includes a mechanism to take a dictionary and produce JSON from it:

http://github.com/schwa/TouchJSON

The example code from that page:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"b" forKey:@"a"];
NSError *error = NULL;
NSData *jsonData = [[CJSONDataSerializer serializer] serializeObject:dictionary error&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

The interface for [this framework](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) seems pretty straight forward to use for generating JSON.